# Use a string variable name for mongodb collection name

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've created a string

```
new_collection_name = "new_name"
```

And then tried to use that variable to reference the collection without any success.

```
for item in db.new_collection_name.find():
```

Is it actually possible to do this using a variable, or should I change my approach?

Comment: `db.getCollection(new_collection_name).find()`

Comment: You should be able to index with variable name as: db[new_collection_name].find()

Comment: Thanks guys, both suggestions work great. Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the vars() function to use a string to select another object.

> The vars method returns the **dict** attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object if the same has a **dict** attribute

```
for item in vars()['db.' + new_collection_name].find():
```